# Convergence of $ \int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sin x\ln x}\, dx $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Does the following integral converge or diverge? 
>   $$ \int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sin x\ln x}\, dx $$

When $x \in [0,1/2] , \sin x>0$ and $\ln x<0$. Therefore $-1/(\sin x\ln x)>0$, which means I can use the comparision test.

$$ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sin x\ln x}dx  <  \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\ln x}dx $$

I don't know what to do next in order to prove convergence (which I think is the answer). Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 1$, so compare to $\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dx}{x\ln x}$.

Comment: your integral does not converge on the given interval

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you, i was mistaken all along.

Comment: @ClementC.i saw it, im trying it now, thank you.

Comment: Even more simply, $$\sin x\leqslant\frac{x}2$$ on the interval considered hence $$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sin x\cdot\ln x}\leqslant2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\cdot\ln x}=-\infty$$

Comment: @Did Did you mean $\sin x \geq \frac{x}{2}$? (The other inequality would be in the wrong direction)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, that is my mistake, this is why i was stuck on it for so long, cause i thought it was diverging, by the way your comprasion worked out for me :)

Comment: No, you expect that the integral diverges to $-\infty$. Hence you want to provide a *lower* bound on  $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ because $\log x<0$, which is an *upper* bound on $\sin x$. Well done Did

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti The first inequality in Did's comment does not hold. What is true in the interval considered is that $\frac{x}{2} \leq \sin x \leq x$ (the second inequality being true for all $x$).

Comment: @ClementC. I didnt check the constant, but we know for sure that $ax\le \sin x \le bx$ for some $a,b$ and all $x \in [0,1/2]$. I was just saying that the signs of the inequalities are correct

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Indeed, I realize that it's an upper bound that is needed. My point is that the constant is not right -- as, otherwise, one couldn't have $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$...

Comment: I got your point :)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I meant that. :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that $\frac2\pi x\le\sin(x)\le x$ for $0\le x\le\frac\pi2$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{x\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{\sin(x)\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{x\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$

Comment: how did you get to the sin(x) inequality ?

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/29/   @robjohn I think you should replace $\pi/2$ by $1$ (I edited it, see the comments above)

Comment: Since $\log x < 0$, the series of inequalities should be reversed. $\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq \sin x \leq x$ implies $\frac{2}{\pi}x\log x\geq \sin x \log x \geq x \log x$.

Comment: @DavidBurstein: $\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$ and since $\sin(0)=0$ and $\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)=1$, the bound $\sin(x)\ge\frac2\pi x$ follows.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: thanks for catching that. I was thinking about it when I wrote the answer and then just plotzed.